# Specify Teams within hierarchy?

Tags: administration

Is there a way to have a Hierarchy in salesforce but split in Teams somewhere else? For example we have something like this:

Senior Broker A   Senior Broker B

Junior Broker A   Junior Broker B

Team Assistant A  Team Assistant B

Now Senior Broker A should see everything from Junior Broker A, but not from Junior Broker B.

Is there a way to achieve this, without having to create every Team as it's own role in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by using roles. We had a consultant who told us this is the best way and we really get the most out of this.

We set it up like:

1. Broker Teammanager A

   - Senior Broker
   - Junior Broker
   - Team Assistant

---

2. Broker Teammanager B

   - Senior Broker
   - Junior Broker
   - Team Assistant

etc.

We don't have to set anything else up and everybody sees what they are supposed to see.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring ’15 you can share records with manager groups.

Here is the official description:

> With Spring ’15, you can use manager groups to share records with your
>   management chain, instead of all managers in the same role based on
>   the role hierarchy. Manager groups can be used wherever other groups
>   are used, such as in a manual share or sharing rule.

More about: [Sharing Records with Manager Groups](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_managers_only.htm&language=en_US)

[image]

Comment: I know this was not in my requirement, but will this restrict a user from the same role, for example Senior Broker A to see the records of Senior Broker B?